# download automatically custom woocommerce export csv file

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

need help on the setup of the auto download.

Here the idea I want to implement.. I have a custom function to export woocommerce order to csv file. it was a manually downloaded from shop order>>action>>export to csv file.

But now I want when order is completed...the csv file auto generate and saved on server or sent to any other server

here's my custom function

```
    // We Create Function To Register In The Dropdown Post Table
function action_bulk_register_function(){
global $post_type;

// filter if you want only in customposttype
if($post_type == 'shop_order') { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        //Add an option to the Bulk actions drop-downs at the top and bottom of the page
        jQuery('<option>').val('TESTCSV').text("<?php _e('Export order in CSV format')?>").appendTo("select[name='action']");
    });
</script>
<?php
  }
   }
     //process the bulk action///
 add_action('load-edit.php', 'process_the_action_customposttype');

function process_the_action_customposttype(){
global $typenow;
if(isset($_REQUEST['post'])) {
    $post_ids = array_map('intval', $_REQUEST['post']);
}

if(empty($post_ids)) return;
// this is based on wp-admin/edit.php


$post_type = $typenow;
if($post_type == 'shop_order') {
    // get the action
    $wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Posts_List_Table');
    $action = $wp_list_table->current_action();
    // Set The Action From Value Option You Created
    $allowed_actions = array("TESTCSV");
    if(!in_array($action, $allowed_actions)) return;
    // Here Add What You Want To

   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv');
                $stream = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
                fputcsv($stream, $csv_header);
        foreach($arrCSV as $key => $assoc_row){
            $numeric_row = array();
            foreach ($csv_header as $header_name) {
                mb_convert_variables('UTF-8', $assoc_row[$header_name]);
                $numeric_row[] = $assoc_row[$header_name];
            }
            fputcsv($stream, $numeric_row);
        }
    }



    exit();
} // end shop order
 }

  require_once(get_stylesheet_directory().'test.php');
```

Comment: How far have you gotten? What kind of wall are you running into? What do you think is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: i have tried some scripts to run in woocommerce thanku page...actually first thing is to make the csv file downloaded automatically after payment confirmation...i m not getting any idea...still :(